# implementing jacobi algorithm to implement laplace equation

Tags: java

The Algorithm traverses a 2D NxN array, making every element the average of its 4 surrounding neighbors (left, right, top, down).

The NxN array has initially all zeros and is surrounded by a margin with all 1’s as shown in
the example below. The 1’s never change, and the 0’s increase little by little.

```
             1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
             1 0 0 0 0 0 0 1
             1 0 0 0 0 0 0 1
             1 0 0 0 0 0 0 1
             1 0 0 0 0 0 0 1
             1 0 0 0 0 0 0 1
             1 0 0 0 0 0 0 1
             1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
```

I have implemented the following code and and am getting array index out of bounds exception . pls correct me .

```
my code :
       public class Main {
static int NO_OF_THREADS =8;

/**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO code application logic here
      Jacobi jacobi = new Jacobi(NO_OF_THREADS);
      jacobi.initialize();
      jacobi.create_threads();
    }

  }//end of Main class

  public class Jacobi {
int ROWS=1000,COLS=1000;
private int i;
private int upper=100;//prevents buffer overflow
private int lower=99;//prevents buffer overflow
private int j;
private double[][] jacobi=new double[ROWS][COLS];
private int NO_OF_THREADS;


public Jacobi(int k)
{
    NO_OF_THREADS=k;
}

public  void initialize() {
        for(i=1;i<=upper;i++)
           {
           for(j=1;j<=upper;j++)
                 {

                       if((i==1)||(i==upper)||(j==1)||(j==upper)){
                      jacobi[i][j]=1.0;
                       }

                   else
                          jacobi[i][j]=0.0;


                 }

             }

    }
              public double[][] getJacobi()
              {
                    return jacobi;
              }

              public void create_threads()
              {
                   theThread[] threads=new theThread[NO_OF_THREADS];
                   for(int k=1;k<=NO_OF_THREADS;k++)
                   {
                       threads[k]=new theThread();
                       threads[k].start();
                    }
               }
               //Inner class of Jacobi

             class theThread extends Thread {

               @Override
              public void run()
              {
                   for(int q=2;q<=lower;q++)
                   {

                     System.out.println("The ID of this thread is: "+getName());
                     for(int j=2;j<=lower;j++)
                      {
                        synchronized(Jacobi.this)
                         {

                        jacobi[q][j]=(jacobi[q-1][j]+jacobi[q+1][j]+jacobi[q] [j-1]+jacobi[q][j+1])/4;
                         }//end of synchronized
              }//end of inner for loop


          }//end of for loop
     }
}//end of theThread class
}//end of jacobi class
```

Comment: Not the question you asked, but in looking at your code you synchronize on "this", which refers to your thread, and thus has no real effect. I am guessing your intent is to synchronize between threads, in which case you should synchronize on "Jacobi.this" (the enclosing instance of Jacobi for the thread which is common to all of the created threads).

Comment: I implemented your correction but i am still like puzzled at the output...do i have to make the Thread.sleep(300) in create_threads()???use one more for loop after i start all threads and use threads[k].join()

Comment: still get array index out of bounds exception!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the line

```
int ROWS,COLS=1000;
```

I think you want to change that to

```
int ROWS=1000, COLS=1000;
```

otherwise `ROWS` isn't set up correctly...

Comment: In the original code `ROWS` will be set to `0` instead of `1000`.

Comment: yeah i have corrected those two mistakes i.e setting ROWS=1000 and making synchronized(Jacobi.this) between threads but i am still getting array index out of bounds . so i am trying to fix the upper and lower limits by trial and error but it is still not working .

Comment: @SANJAY RAO: could you post the updated code please? And can you fix the indentation please, it's rather hard to read otherwise :)

Comment: yeah i have edited the same post with corrections talked above .pls let me knw if it is still not easy to read

Comment: Please fix the indentation! Every "{" should be aligned with the corresponding "}", and each "{" should be indented by a consistent amount from the containing "{". At the moment the "}" for "end of inner for loop" is indented less than the "{" for the *outer* "for" loop, and it makes the code very hard to follow. (Your editor program should be able to assist you with this...).